# Suckerfish menu drop down not showing in IE6 and IE7

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position, suckerfish

Normally I would post the code of just the menu but the menu on its own works but when put in the surrounding code this menu fails to work in IE6 and IE7. So the menu can be found in use here: http://block.pd.alphaready.com/

I think the problem I am having here is the IE absolute positioning bug explained here
http://www.brunildo.org/test/IE_raf3.html but I'm stugeling to understand this and apply the fix to my navigation.

Any help please?

Thanks

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. What I found was that < IE8 was reseting z-indexes with relative positioned elements.

So to fix the problem had to remove the relative position on the header and re position my navigation.